# Query for a time range from startTime and endTime fields in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I have a table that has the following fields:

```
uniqueID
startTime
endTime
value
otherData
```

Given a time range of 10:00AM today and 11:00AM today, I want to retrieve all the items where `startTime` and `endTime` fall between the aforementioned time range. Is there a way to do this efficiently?

I can think of one mediocre solution:

1. Make a GSI with a hash key based on hour in the day for even partitioning, and make the `startTime` the range key.
2. This way I can query for a `startTime` with condition of `startTime` >= 10:00AM today. Then I will have to add a filter expression for `endTime` <= 11:00AM today. The filtering part will be inefficient.

Is there a better way for this in DynamoDB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3 methods:

1) your GSI approach
  2) a Scan: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#QueryAndScan.Scan
May work for you if you don't have a lot of data
   3) make startTime into the range key for the table and query on that (without a GSI)

If using the GSI keep in mind that they are eventually consistent (ie you might not get a record in your query after you immediately update it)

Comment: 2) Scan wouldn't be good as there is too much data.
3) The uniqueID has no correlation to a startTime, I don't see how this works? If I want to do a query on the range key, I need to also supply a hash key, which in this case would be the uniqueID. Is this what you meant?

Comment: uniqueID would be the hashKey and startTime would be the rangeKey.

Comment: That still means I need to filter by endTime right? Which means it's the same as the GSI solution. Actually, the GSI solution makes more sense since I would be partitioning the data into hourly buckets with the GSI hash key.

Comment: yup. you still need to check the endTime. The point of the answer was to show you how you could do it. GSI is probably the right way to do it in 95% of cases